# How to have netplan config applied automatically after startup on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: networking, server, 22.04, netplan

I am running Ubuntu 22.04.3 on a dual-boot hp laptop and I have the following configuration file `/etc/netplan/10-network-config_home.yaml` defined:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enx00e04c680202:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.200.100/24
      routes:
       - to: default
         via: 192.168.200.220
         metric: 200
      link-local: [ ipv4, ipv6 ]
```

After booting the laptop I check the given interface using `ip addr show  dev enx00e04c680202` like 30 minutes after bootup and get the output

```
3: enx00e04c680202: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e0:4c:68:02:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.200.100/24 brd 192.168.200.255 scope global noprefixroute enx00e04c680202
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Connected to that interface is a device with IP address `169.254.1.0` but I am not able to ping that device or connect to that device.

I manually run the following command

```
sudo netplan apply
```

after which the interface looks the same (with `ip addr show  dev enx00e04c680202`):

```
3: enx00e04c680202: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e0:4c:68:02:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.200.100/24 brd 192.168.200.255 scope global noprefixroute enx00e04c680202
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

but THEN I am able to ping that device on address `169.254.1.0` and connect to it.

It seems the netplan plan is not automatically applied after bootup. Can this be fixed, and how can this be fixed if it can be fixed?

Maybe the file `/etc/network/interfaces` is interfering which has the content

```
iface enx00e04c680202 inet static 
    address 192.168.200.100
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 192.168.200.255
```

?

Comment: I suggest removing `/etc/network/interfaces` and uninstalling `net-tools` if it is still on the system. They have been superceded by `netplan` and `iproute2`.

Comment: Suggesting this because I suspect that `net-tools` is doing the `if-up` / `if-down` juggling of your routing tables, for which it will use the information in `/etc/network/interfaces`, which lacks that link-local route that your netplan definition has.

Comment: Cool thanks a lot, that seem to have worked...